# Dynamic URL in express+pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a simple form which returns the username on POST.

```
form(method='POST',action='./users/:username')
    div(class='form-group')
        label(for="username") Username;
        input(class='form-control' type="text" id='username' name='username')
        button(class="btn btn-default") Submit
```

This router greets user :

```js
router.post('/users/:username', function (req , res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    res.send("Hi " + username);
});
```

Everything works fine execpt the URL shows "http://localhost:3000/users/:username" instead of the username entered in form.
What am i missing?

Comment: action in your view has to be actual URL rather than placeholder for :username, there should be actual USERNAME which route will pick and set against `req.body.username`

Comment: Not achievable. You have to either pass the action during response.render or set it simply through javascript before submit. Not related to the answer. Can't your action be just action="./users"? why you need :username ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A direct solution

The route that renders the view needs to pass a variable to it. For example:

Router:

```js
// this is not the POST request, this is the initial render of the view
router.get("/users/:username", function(req, res) {
    res.render("viewPath", { username: req.params.username });
    // of course, replace the 'viewPath' with the actual path to your view
});
```

View:

```
form(method='POST', action='./users/' + username)
```

## A logical solution

As a comment suggested, you don't need the `/:username` in the POST route. You can omit it, as the username is passed in the body. You can just do:

```
router.post('/users', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    res.send("Hi " + username);
});
```